# Exclude the ID's that do not follow a sequence

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with different stages of different ID's.

I need to include only those IR's that are in phase 1, or phase 1 and 2, or phase 1,2 and 3, or phase 1,2,3 and 4. Col C in the attached table is the desired output.
*** ID 1 is included, because it has Stage 1 and 2. ID2 has stage 1,2,3 and 4, hence included. If there are any stages that does not include all the prior stages, then that needs to be excluded, hence ID3 and 4 are excluded because they have stage 2,3,4 and 4 only respectively

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Interesting problem. Could be a stretch, but what about:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND(CONCAT(SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(B$2:B$21,A$2:A$21=A2)))),"1234"),0)=1,"Y","N")
```

Comment: **Note:** Normally I would vote to close a question that lacks research details and/or any effort for debugging details. I admit to be partially inconsequent in this case due to the problem being intricate and interesting. I'm only human =). Next time make sure to read: [ask] a question with a [mcve] and see [how much effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) is required from your end before posting.

Answer (score 2):

For those that do not have Office 365.

Use SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS()):

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(
     COUNTIFS([ID],[@ID],[Stage],ROW($ZX$1:INDEX($ZX:$ZX,AGGREGATE(14,7,[Stage]/([ID]=[@ID]),1))))/
     (COUNTIFS([ID],[@ID],[Stage],ROW($ZX$1:INDEX($ZX:$ZX,AGGREGATE(14,7,[Stage]/([ID]=[@ID]),1))))+
     (COUNTIFS([ID],[@ID],[Stage],ROW($ZX$1:INDEX($ZX:$ZX,AGGREGATE(14,7,[Stage]/([ID]=[@ID]),1))))=0)))=
     AGGREGATE(14,7,[Stage]/([ID]=[@ID]),1),"Y","N")
```

[image]

---

Another Office 365 Formula that works similar to above:

```
=IF(COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER([Stage],[ID]=[@ID])))=MAXIFS([Stage],[ID],[@ID]),"Y","N")
```

[image]